# Definition of Structs (main)

Tags: c, pointers, struct

for example I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int dia, mes, ano;
} Data;

int main() {
    Data data[5]; //line 6
    return 0;
}
```

in `Data` is basically the `typedef` - the name we assign to a type (line 6)

on the date would be what? (line 6) - A variable of what type?

Comment: The question does not make a sense.

Comment: I'm asking about Data data on main. I don't understand the "data". If you are part of a struct data... In my "Data data" view would be ....... typedef = Data, struct name = data

Comment: Read at last a book on C for beginners. It will be useful for you.

Comment: can't you asnwer?

Comment: Your question has been already answered.

Comment: please it didn't cost you anything :/ I read and understood but I'm having doubts on the date[5]

Answer (score 2):

`Data data[5];` declares `data` to be an array of 5 `Data`.

`Data` is a name for the structure type, because `typedef` declares an alternate name for a type.

The type is `struct { int dia, mes, ano; }`. However, this cannot be used as a name for the type because of rules about structures and tags—each definition of a structure without a tag defines a unique type. If `struct { int dia, mes, ano; }` appears again where the first declaration is visible, it defines a new type that is a different type from the earlier one even though they have the same members.

If the structure were declared with a tag, as in `struct foo { int dia, mes, ano; }`, then `struct foo` would be a usable name for the same type.

Since `Data` was created in the `typedef` that first defined the type, it can be used as a name for the type.

Comment: Basically, typedef gives a new name to a "type". I was asking the "Data data". Is "Data" specific to typedef and "data"?

Comment: Basically the "date" is a name of a structure? For example typedef struct foo {}Data;                        Data foo;